# What is the correct way to enter code snippets?

Tags: discussion, design

How do you enter code so that it presents a "Run Snippet" button at the bottom?

I have tried using [ code ] [ /code ] and < code > < /code > tags (without the spaces)
and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> before pasting code into thread (with and without four leading spaces).

In most cases I get an error message that the code is not formatted correctly or it is accepted, but the "Run Snippet" button is not present. How do you enter different sections for HTML, CSS and JavaScript code?

What is the correct sequence that appears to be eluding me?

Some kind of administrator edited my code in another thread, so I know it can be done. I just have not figured out the magic yet.

Comment: While in the editor, press Ctrl + M. Or click the icon right next to the Add Image icon which is "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet".